# authenticate windows git for github

Tags: git, powershell, github

Git for windows can cache authenticated https credentials. The problem is that github incorrectly returns a 404 for secure repositories if credentials aren't provided, instead of the proper 401 response. Obviously windows therefore has no way to know that it should prompt for credentials.

How do I get around this? I don't want to be forced to use the bash prompt for anything github related, as it doesn't integrate well with other windows applications, nor do I want to use the github client. I want to use the git command line from powershell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace HTTPS with SSH + ssh-agent.

Comment: Also, 404 _is_ the proper, secure response. 401 gives out abusable information: it tells the client that the account exists. Responsible service providers like GitHub do their best not to give that sort of information away to unathenticated attackers.

Comment: This is just security through obscurity. There is nothing proper or secure about it. It's a clunky hack implemented by engineers that should know better.

Comment: 401 is the proper response. Anything else is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In windows, the _netrc is the equivalent of .netrc. Adding an entry in there with a personal access token solved the problem.